# Expectation of constraint random walk

Tags: expectation, random-walk

## Problem description

I am currently dealing with a practical problem that can be simplified to something like this:

- I start by setting a value to 0
- Every minute, I try to increase or decrease 1 or decrease this value by 1.
- My value cannot be negative, so if my value is 0 and I try to decrease it, nothing happens.

I believe this is called a constraint random walk, and hereby present my question:

**I want to know what the expectation of my value is if I keep walking like this forever.**

Any solution will do, but a simple intuitive approach would of course be preferred.

---

## Progress so far

I have already established that the expectation of the value increases as time progresses by this logic:
If your value at time `t` is `Vt`, then, at any time greater than `t+Vt` there is a positive chance that you hit the constraint. Without hitting the constraint the distribution is symetrical around `Vt`, and due to the chance of hitting it you increase the expectation.

However, I am aware that a series that keeps increasing may converge, so I am at a loss to prove or show whether the expecation goes to infinity if you just keep walking forever.

Comment: "the expectation of my value is if I keep walking like this forever" The expected value goes to +oo when the time goes to +oo.

Comment: @Did That was my intuition as well, however I could not find a proof or strong reasoning for this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the symmetric random walk $(S_n)$ on the integers, defined by $S_0=0$ and $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ for every $n\geqslant1$, where $(X_n)$ is i.i.d. with $P(X_n=1)=P(X_n=-1)=\frac12$. Introduce $M_n=\max\{S_0,S_1,\ldots,S_n\}$ and $Y_n=M_n-S_n$. Then:

> The dynamics of the process $(Y_n)$ is the dynamics described in the question.$^*$

Now, $E(S_n)=0$ hence $E(Y_n)=E(M_n)$ and it is known that $E(M_n)\sim\sqrt{2n/\pi}$ hence $E(Y_n)\to\infty$.

$^*$ To see why, consider the dynamics of $(Y_n)$.

- If $Y_n\geqslant1$, then $M_n\geqslant S_n+1$ hence the fact that $S_{n+1}\leqslant S_n+1$ almost surely implies that $M_{n+1}=M_n$ almost surely, thus $Y_{n+1}=Y_n-X_{n+1}$, that is, $Y_{n+1}=Y_n+1$ or $Y_{n+1}=Y_n-1$ with equal probabilities.
- If $Y_n=0$, then  $M_n=S_n$ hence $M_{n+1}=S_{n+1}$ if $X_{n+1}=+1$ while $M_{n+1}=M_n$ and $S_{n+1}=S_n-1$ if $X_{n+1}=-1$, that is, $Y_{n+1}=0$ or $Y_{n+1}=+1$ with equal probabilities.

These are the desired transition probabilities. To sum up, $$Y_{n+1}=\max(Y_n-X_{n+1},0).$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't see why $Y_n$ matches the dynamics of the question. For example: `X = [1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 1]` then `S = [1 2 3 2 1 0 -1 -2 -1]` and `M = [1 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3]` so `Y = [0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 4]` but based on this `X` the value I am interested in would be: `V = [1 2 3 2 1 0 0 0 1]`

Comment: I fail to understand the objection: how do you define "the value you are interested in, based on this X"? The sequence Y = [1 2 3 2 1 0 0 0 1] corresponds to S = [-1 -2 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 1] which corresponds to X = [-1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1], that is, the mirror X-sequence of the X-sequence you suggest.

Comment: When I try `X = [-1 -1 -1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 -1]` your Y indeed matches my V. However when I try `X = [+1 +1 +1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 +1]` I don't see the match. Perhaps I just need to clear my mind a bit.